# CSS3, how to make my Gradient WebKit Background Transparent?

Tags: html, webkit, css

I have the following line of CSS:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#243d63), to(#1a2638));
```

How can I make the background transparent, ie an opacity of .9, so the user can see what's under the div that has this style? Just for WebKit only concern...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use rgba

```
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(255,52,21,0.2)), to(#000), color-stop(.6,#000));
```

rgba syntax is as so: `rgba(redInDecimal,greenInDecimal,blueInDecimal,alphaFrom0To1);`

http://jsfiddle.net/PxnXn/1/